# Is there safer DSL implement in ruby

Tags: ruby, dsl

I want to implement a DSL  for external use which should contain basic arithmetic, conditional and loop. But I can not eval ruby directly, it is not safe.

Is there any safer way to eval ruby code or is there scaffold to create a pure plain text DSL.